# Animating complete CollectionViewCell instead of Image

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, cabasicanimation

I am trying to add a shake animation to my `collectionViewCells` whenever I press the `editButton`.

I found code doing the animation here on StackOverFlow:

```
let cell : SettingsCollectionViewCell = mainCollectionView!.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexpath) as! SettingsCollectionViewCell

        let shake:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        shake.duration = 0.1
        shake.repeatCount = 2
        shake.autoreverses = true


        let from_point:CGPoint = CGPointMake(cell.center.x - 5, cell.center.y)
        let from_value:NSValue = NSValue(CGPoint: from_point)

        let to_point:CGPoint = CGPointMake(cell.center.x + 5, cell.center.y)
        let to_value:NSValue = NSValue(CGPoint: to_point)

        shake.fromValue = from_value
        shake.toValue = to_value
        cell.layer.addAnimation(shake, forKey: "position")
```

it works perfectly when I try this on my `cell.collectionImage` but in this case not on my cell itself. Any ideas?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Is there any animation at all? Where in the controller do you put that code?

Comment: I doesn't animate at all using the cell.layer. I put the code in a button method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to address the `contentView` of the `UICollectionCell`

```
cell.collectionView.frame.center.x
```